# Razor does not trigger named handler if property has [Required] annotaion

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, unobtrusive-validation

I have a simple form, with some post handlers. I only want to submit the form when input is not empty.

```
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Feedback" />
    <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Test">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
public void OnPost() {}

public void OnPostTest() {}
```

when I don't have the `[Required]` annotation on the `Feedback` property, it correctly triggers the `OnPostTest()` method, when I click on the submit button. But I do want the required validation.

```
public string Feedback { get; set; }
```

however, when I add the `[Required]` annotation, it always triggers the `OnPost()` method, when I click on the submit button. But I want to trigger the `OnPostTest()` method.

```
[Required]
public string Feedback { get; set; }
```

I thought `asp-page-handler` is straightforward, what am I missing?

I am using .NET Core 3.1

Comment: That sounds wrong... maybe something else is going on. `OnPostTest` should be called, just with `ModelState.IsValid == false`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thank you for confirming that. I find the culprit is in an extension js file, where we used the `submitHandler` from jQuery Validation. I'll add that to my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I find the culprit in an extension JavaScript file, where we used the [submitHandler](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler) from jQuery Validation:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
}
```

Stepping through this code, I find the `form.action` does not have the handler, e.g. `"https://localhost:44352/TestPage"`. So the `formaction` on the button didn't
[overrides the `action` attribute of the button's form owner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formaction), which is something I didn't expected.

Anyway, the `event.submitter.formAction` does have the handler in it, e.g. `"https://localhost:44352/TestPage?handler=Test"`, so I fixed it by assigning it to the form action.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    if ((event.submitter && event.submitter.formAction 
         && form.action !== event.submitter.formAction) {
        form.action = event.submitter.formAction;
    }
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Typically users of ASP cannot call `.validate()` thanks to Unobtrusive Validation, so they override the plugin options via the `.setDefaults()` method of jQuery Validate.